# Why is Java giving me unusual results to basic arithmetic with doubles?

Tags: java, double

I'm writing some intelligence for a virtual rover driving around on Mars picking up resources. I have the following code:

```
public Point getPointFromRoverOffset(double offsetX, double offsetY) {
    double x = offsetX + currentLocation.x;
    double y = offsetY + currentLocation.y;

    if(x > getWorldWidth()) {
        x = x - getWorldWidth();
    }
    else if (x < 0) {
        x = getWorldWidth() + x;
    }

    if(y > getWorldHeight()) {
        y = y - getWorldHeight();
    }
    else if(y < 0) {
        y = getWorldHeight() + y;
    }

    getLog().info("Based on location " + currentLocation.toString());
    getLog().info("Decided that offset (" + offsetX + "," + offsetY + ") = (" + x + "," + y + ")");
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

All the numbers involved are doubles, representing a 2d vector in a 2d plane.

getWorldWidth() and getWorldHeight() both return 20.0

Im getting the following strange results:

```
[INFO] 16:41 Versatile - Based on location (0.0,6.0)
[INFO] 16:41 Versatile - Decided that offset (0.0,-5.999999999999999) = (0.0,8.881784197001252E-16)
```

Seemingly the input Y value -5.9 (recurring, a double rounding fault), and the current Y position 0.6 so the value should have been 0.1. Yet it comes out as 8.88 (et al).

Why? Is this some odd behaviour of doubles that I'm not aware of? Or am I missing something more obvious?

Comment: It's not `8.8`, it's `8.8....E-16`, that being `8.8..... * 10^-16`. So essentially 0.

Comment: And `-5.999999...` (recurring) is not "-5.9", it is effectively `-6`, so the value should not have been `0.1` but `0.0` (which it kind of is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`8.881784197001252E-16` is a very small number. it is approx 0.000000000000000888 or 8.88*10^-16. It is the difference between the value with a slight rounding error and the expect value.

If you need values to be exact, I suggest either

- round the doubles
- use a small allowed error in your calculations e.g. ERR = 1e-6
- use integers (by scaling everything by 1000 for example)
- use BigDecimal.

Comment: Ah, so the negative symbol before the 16 was denoting that it was actually extremely small. I thought it was greater than 8. Thanks.